# Consolidate all balances in one field

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have this query result, in which every particular has its column to display the balances.

```
Id  AccountNumber   Particular  Inst1_Balance   Inst2_Balance   Inst3_Balance   Inst4_Balance   Inst5_Balance
1   99921           Inst5       0.00            0.00            0.00            0.00            232.50
1   99921           Inst3       0.00            0.00            170.00          0.00            0.00
3   86123           Inst3       0.00            0.00            843.00          0.00            0.00    
4   76543           Inst2       0.00            123.00          0.00            0.00            0.00
5   12323           Inst4       0.00            0.00            0.00            1000.00         0.00
5   12323           Inst2       0.00            75.00           0.00            0.00            0.00
5   12323           Inst1       2765.00         0.00            0.00            0.00            0.00
7   23243           Inst5       0.00            0.00            0.00            0.00            865.00
8   43467           Inst2       0.00            435.00          0.00            0.00            0.00
9   67543           Inst3       0.00            0.00            1234.00         0.00            0.00
10  33245           Inst2       0.00            111.00          0.00            0.00            0.00
11  88881           Inst2       0.00            222.00          0.00            0.00            0.00
12  99931           Inst1       767.00          0.00            0.00            0.00            0.00
12  99931           Inst2       0.00            2345.00         0.00            0.00            0.00
```

From the above table I want to consolidate the balances of the particulars into a single column.

```
Id  AccountNumber   Particular  Balance
1   99921           Inst5       232.50
1   99921           Inst3       170.00
3   86123           Inst3       843.00
4   76543           Inst2       123.00
5   12323           Inst4       1000.00
5   12323           Inst2       75.00
5   12323           Inst1       2765.00
7   23243           Inst5       865.00
8   43467           Inst2       435.00
9   67543           Inst3       1234.00
10  33245           Inst2       111.00
11  88881           Inst2       222.00
12  99931           Inst1       767.00
12  99931           Inst2       2345.00




;WITH tmptable AS  (  
    SELECT INS.CustomerId AS 'Id',
        INS.Particular AS 'Particular',
        CONCAT(CON.AccountNumber) AS 'AcctNumber',
        COALESCE(SUM(case when particular = 'Inst1' then [Bal] else 0 end),0) AS 'Inst1Bal',
        COALESCE(SUM(case when particular = 'Inst2' then [Bal] else 0 end),0) AS 'Inst2Bal',
        COALESCE(SUM(case when particular = 'Inst3' then [Bal] else 0 end),0) AS 'Inst3Bal',
        COALESCE(SUM(case when particular = 'Inst4' then [Bal] else 0 end),0) AS 'Inst4Bal',
        COALESCE(SUM(case when particular = 'Inst5' then [Bal] else 0 end),0) AS 'Inst5Bal'
FROM [Installment] INS
LEFT JOIN Customer CONS
ON INS.CustomerId = CON.Id
GROUP BY INS.CustomerId,
    CON.AccountNumber
    INS.Particular
)
SELECT Id,
    AcctNumber,
    Particular,
    CAST(Inst1Bal AS numeric(18,2))  AS 'Inst1_Balance',
    CAST(Inst2Bal AS numeric(18,2))  AS 'Inst2_Balance',
    CAST(Inst3Bal AS numeric(18,2))  AS 'Inst3_Balance',
    CAST(Inst4Bal AS numeric(18,2))  AS 'Inst4_Balance',
    CAST(Inst5Bal AS numeric(18,2))  AS 'Inst5_Balance'
FROM tmptable
```

So far, I have this code which displays the data based on the first table.I need help in consolidating the 5 balances column into a single column as shown on the second table. Can it be done using JOIN?

Comment: Do you ask to edit your first table query or to achieve the second table? `I am contemplating to use UNION but I need recommendations/suggestions and have it in a single query.` << I am not sure about the question

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Yeah what actually is your question, you already have a query, does it do what you want or not? You also know a way to do it i.e. union, so go for it? What do you need help with?

Comment: Umm, the original data you're working with is already in the format you want, so just remove the aggregation and make a straight select out of it? Right now you're asking on how to make tomatoes out of a pizza recipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current query is a pivot query. Looks like what you want is a simple qroup by query.

```
SELECT INS.CustomerId AS Id,
       CON.AccountNumber AS AcctNumber,
       INS.Particular AS Particular,
       SUM([Bal]) AS Balance
FROM   [Installment] INS
LEFT JOIN Customer CON
       ON INS.CustomerId = CON.Id
GROUP BY INS.CustomerId,
         CON.AccountNumber,
         INS.Particular;
```

Comment: wait, your aliasing is messed up. Sometime it's `CONS`, sometimes `CON`. It's great you exclude the concat things in account number field hehehe

Comment: Fixed the alias. Thanks

Comment: The alias was messed up in the original question.